# Get profiler toolbar in demo

Tags: symfony-3.1

I don't manage to get the Symfony 3.1 profiler toolbar in demo environment

AppKernel.php : bundles are enabled for demo

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'demo'], true)) {
     $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
     $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
     $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
     $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
     $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
}
```

---

config_demo.yml

```
framework:
  router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_demo.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
  profiler: false

web_profiler:
  toolbar: true
  intercept_redirects: false
```

---

app_demo.php

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('demo', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

---

routing_demo.yml

```
_wdt:
  resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
  prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
  resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
  prefix:   /_profiler
```

and yes, I have body tag in my home page

What am I missing ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK my mistake

My demo htaccess was using app.php and not app_demo.php

sorry !